# Need a design for simple switching circuit

Tags: transistors, switching, biasing

I am trying to build a simple switching circuit using a transistor. I have a 6V source that I need to switch using a 2.7v "signal". So if signal output is at 2.7v, I need transistor to be closed and if signal is at 1.5v, the transistor needs to be open. (I can also work with reverse states).

I have a PN2222A, but if alternate components are more suitable, I can procure those. Is there a reference circuit I can begin with?

Here's an initial concept of my idea:
[image: My initial idea]

The exact output level is not important, as long as it switches between values >2.3v and <2.3v for the open/close states.

The exact source impedance is unknown (can I just measure with a multimeter?) but a good guess is 1 MOhm.

Also, the exact output impedance is unknown, but can be assumed to be large. Again, 1M would be a good guess.

Comment: Please show a schematic of your design so far (you can edit and use the tool)

Comment: We'd need to know what power supply rails you have available or can make available to the circuit. Also, it sounds like you want to switch 6 V for a load that requires 6 V but want to use a signal line that guarantees at least 2.7 V for one state and no more than 1.5 V for another. But I'm not sure I'm reading it right. Also, no info on the source impedance, just those voltage levels, so far as I can tell. Need more info.

Comment: Add a resistor of 2K or so between your input and the base of the transistor.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use 2 NPN’s as a Darlington, requires 1.2 to turn on so divide the input voltage with a series R just a bit greater than your source impedance to get 2/3’rds of the no load voltage like 2M if your  source is 1M.
2. This will be enough to drive a collector R of > 1k.
3. To help turn off, , add 100k   Between 2nd base to ground in case of leakage or
   noise. And add a small cap if you get interference.

Answer (score 0):

In the schematic shown, the output is low when the input signal is greater than 0.6 V, and high when the input signal is less than 0.4 V (-ish).  To shift the transition levels to higher voltages, a simple way is to add signal diodes in series with the base.  At these low currents, each diode will add less than 0.6 V.  Adding three diodes (1N914, 1N4148, etc.) will raise the transition level to approx. 2.3 V.  To assure a fast and complete turn-off, add a resistor (something between 10 K and 100 K) from the transistor base to GND.

Also, look into the terms source impedance and output impedance.  The output impedance of the circuit is way below 1 M.  You probably mean 'load impedance', the impedance of whatever is downstream, being driven by this circuit.